# Add Html tags in Product Feature

Tags: html, prestashop

I need to save html tags in features section of the create/edit product page.

I have changed `TYPE_HTML` and `isCleanHTML` in classes/FeatureValue.php, but the validation still ignores html tags.

Ex.

```
'value' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
```

Thank you.

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oazsh.png)

Comment: I use Prestashop.1.7

Comment: Ok. But we need some code to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `definition` of ***FeatureValue*** and change it so it can save HTML as well as need to change code in file where it is saving product custom feature value. Rather than changing in ***core files***, I will make use of ***Overrides***.

Follow below mentioned steps.

1) Create file `Product.php` file on path `override\classes` and put below code in it. This will save `HTML` in value field.

```
<?php
/**
 * @override Product.php
 */

class Product extends ProductCore
{
    /**
     * Add new feature to product
     */
    public function addFeaturesCustomToDB($id_value, $lang, $cust)
    {
        $row = array('id_feature_value' => (int)$id_value, 'id_lang' => (int)$lang, 'value' => pSQL($cust, true));
        return Db::getInstance()->insert('feature_value_lang', $row);
    }
}
```

2) Create `FeatureValue.php` file on path `override\classes` and put below code in it. Changing `definition` so that it can validate HTML.

```
<?php
/**
 * @override FeatureValue.php
 */

class FeatureValue extends FeatureValueCore
{
    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'feature_value',
        'primary' => 'id_feature_value',
        'multilang' => true,
        'fields' => array(
            'id_feature' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
            'custom' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),

            /* Lang fields */
            'value' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
        ),
    );
}
```

3) To `autoload` newly created override class files; delete `class_index.php` file from `var\cache\dev` and `var\cache\prod` folder.

Hope it will help you!